# "Real time" answer in a conversion program

Tags: java, android

How to code in java for real time output which displayed on the screen,as soon as user inputs some value with keyboard, with out a calculate button in activity in a simple conversion program? I have given the code below. In that it takes one input value and "FROM" and "TO" to convert the value and showed in the display with press of "calculate" button

Now I want to eliminate the "calculate" button and as soon as user inputs the numbers want to show the answer to the display

My code given below. Please let me know any additional information required

```
package sujaynambiar.textilecalculation;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LengthConverter extends AppCompatActivity {

private Spinner spinner11, spinner21;
private EditText from;
private TextView to;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.lenght_converter);

Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit1);
from = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.InputEditText1);
to = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.OutputTextView1);
spinner11 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner11);
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add("Kilometer");
list1.add("Meter");
list1.add("Centimeter");
list1.add("Millimeter");
list1.add("Feet");
list1.add("Yard");
list1.add("Inch");
list1.add("Mile");

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
          dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner11.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
spinner21 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner21);
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
list2.add("Kilometer");
list2.add("Meter");
list2.add("Centimeter");
list2.add("Millimeter");
list2.add("Feet");
list2.add("Yard");
list2.add("Inch");
list2.add("Mile");

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list2);
dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner21.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
}

public void onClick(View v)
{

int index1 = spinner11.getSelectedItemPosition();
int index2 = spinner21.getSelectedItemPosition();
double value = 0;
if (from.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.toastmessage1),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
else {
    value = Double.parseDouble(from.getText().toString());
}
//From Kilometer
if (index1 == 0 && index2 == 0 )//N

{
    double result = value*1;
    to.setText(result+"");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a text change listener.

```
from.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                calculateNewResult(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

You may also want to use an item select listener on the spinners.

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        updateTheCalculation();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Dear Mr.Colon GIllespie. Could you please give some sample code for text change listeners and item select listeners. I am implementing the abouve codes but getting lots of errors. I am not sure whether i am doing it in right way